# Still getting CORS error in Chrome after adding headers in Node.js Express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xml, cors

I'm trying to do a simple `GET` request to a `XML` file, and I'm stuck on this `CORS` error.

I've tried multiple solutions including adding the headers manually in my `server.js` file, and using the `cors` NPM package. With both of those, if I hit the endpoint in Postman, I can see the headers attached to the request, as well as the response.

However in Google Chrome, the headers are not being attached to the request. Here's the code in my `index.html` file:

```html
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <script src="./server.js"></script>  -->
  <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', http://11.111.111.111/web/data/data.xml, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') 
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send(null);
  </script>
</body>
```

Note that I've replaced the URL of the XML page I'm trying to get information from with a placeholder.

Here's the code in my `server.js` file:

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");
var cors = require('cors')
// Sets up the Express App
var app = express();

var PORT = 3000;
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes

// Sets up the Express app to handle data parsing
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
   //res.set({
   // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ['*'],
   // 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
   // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
   // });
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
  console.log('hit me')
  console.log(res);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send('Houston, we have a problem.')
});

// Starts the server to begin listening
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
});
```

And here's a screen-shot from the postman output
[image: screenshot from dev-tools]

I added `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` to my client-side `xhr` request, and I switched to using the `cors` package. Now I get this error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I added `app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes` as explained in the `npm cors` documentation, but I still get the same error. However the headers are attached to the request in the dev-tools. I've updated the code and screenshots on this post to reflect these changes.

screenshot from dev-tools:
[image: screenshot from dev-tools]

Comment: Have you tried adding the Chrome CORS extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: @John while the plugin sounds useful in theory, it'll only put off problems until after you deploy to prod.

Comment: yes It works with the extension, but I need it to work without it.

Comment: yeah, so... you didn't set CORS headers on the response for the static file. You only set them on the /test route.

Comment: @KevinB thank you for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: I removed the offensive language which was contained in your code, as there was no need for it. Please keep in mind that contributions should remain professional on Stack Exchange sites. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally heard back from that team and it turns out the server is configured to block all cors requests.

Answer (score -1):

If it is just for local testing try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
or try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors.

import cors from 'cors'

app.use(cors())

Comment: yup i've tried using the `cors` npm package and i have the same issue